# Using react-infinite-scroll-component with a predefined array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have an array called filtered which is fill with events.

I am trying to implement this infinite scroll with my current array.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component

I have the following code.

```
const recentActivity = this.state.filtered
.sort( (a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date) )
.map ((array) =>
    <div className="row content-timeline " key={array.id}>
      <div className="col-1 activityIcon">{this.activityIcon(array.source.toString().toLowerCase())}</div>
      <ReactTooltip effect="solid"/>
      <div className="col-11">
        <span className="recentActivityTagHeader">{array.tag === undefined ? array.source : array.tag} <span className="smallGrey">({array.mtn.substr(array.mtn.length - 4)})</span></span>
        <div className="recentActivityDescription">{array.description}</div>
        <div className="recentActivityDate">{styleDateTime(array.date)}</div>
      </div>

    </div>
);
```

I have this InfiniateScroll object as well..

```
<InfiniteScroll
    dataLength={this.state.filtered.length}
    next={this.fetchMoreData}
    hasMore={true}
    loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}>
        {recentActivity}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Here is the fetchMoreData function

```
fetchMoreData = () => {
      // a fake async api call like which sends
      // 20 more records in 1.5 secs
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          filtered: this.state.filtered.concat(Array.from({ length: 200 }))
        });
      }, 1500);
    };
```

This is not doing any type of limited div or creating a infinite scroll.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
My problem is how I fill my filtered array with setting the state. I need a better way to do that.

```
componentDidMount() {


  this.props.touchpointsPayload.data.map((array) =>
    {if (array.sources !== undefined) {
        array.sources.map((sources) =>
          sources.events.map((events) =>
            this.setState(acctInsights => ({
              sources: [...acctInsights.sources, events],
              filtered: [...acctInsights.sources, events]
            }))
          )
        )

    }}

  );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your `dataLength` need to be based on `items` and not `filtered`?

Comment: my array is the this.state.filtered. the example they have is the stat is holding 20 items.. if you look at the example. i dont want to use items because it will have no idea where my data is.

Comment: Well, the lengths aren't going to match because you're using the length of the actual object not the filtered object.

Comment: yeah i changed it. the problem is how i append my filtered array... see the above question for updated code.....